# Receiving a Parse notification and opening the app via the app Icon to view it not the notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

when I receive a notification I use this code in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

So if the app is opened and currently on screen the notification will be displayed or if the application is in the background tapping on the notification will open the app and display it. Is there a way to tap on the app icon and then display the notification? For example, maybe the user sees the notification come through and wants to view it and clicks on the app icon on the home screen. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the app icon won't display anything related to the notification, it will simply load your application per normal use.

However you can set notifications to active tasks once responding to a payload as you stated in your question. Say you send a push notification of a sale going on and they tap on the notification itself you can register tasks to activate upon selection :

Per Parse Docs :

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
. . .
// Extract the notification data
NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

// Create a pointer to the Photo object
NSString *photoId = [notificationPayload objectForKey:@"p"];
PFObject *targetPhoto = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Photo"
                                                      objectId:photoId];

 // Fetch photo object
 [targetPhoto fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    // Show photo view controller
    if (!error && [PFUser currentUser]) {
    PhotoVC *viewController = [[PhotoVC alloc] initWithPhoto:object];
    [self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
  }];
}
```

Alternatively, what you can do is have a dedicated 'Notifications' or 'Messages' HUB or View Controller that has a list of recent notifications for them to reference or select

Comment: yeah there is just no way to view notifications one by one, can only select one which was my problem. Had to implement saving a messages separately to a messages class in Parse and then retrieve them when a push is received. I coded it so when a push is received it will fire a NSNotifcation and then my view controller will listen for this and load messages from the message class. Thanks